# Symfony 6 - Circular reference error while using groups

Tags: symfony, symfony6

I am working on an API developed with Symfony 6.
I am used to work with this framework, but this time i am facing an issue (or i am just blind and not seeing a stupid mistake).

So, here is the code of my entity Truck using the group "show_truck":

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: TruckRepository::class)]
class Truck
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'CUSTOM')]
    #[ORM\Column(type: UuidType::NAME, unique: true)]
    #[ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class: 'doctrine.uuid_generator')]
    #[Groups(['list_trucks', 'show_truck'])]
    private ?Uuid $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 50)]
    #[Groups(['list_trucks', 'show_truck'])]
    private ?string $name = null;
...
    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: FoodCategory::class, inversedBy: 'trucks')]
    private Collection $foodCategories;
...
```

Here is the code of my entity FoodCategory (which is not using the group "show_truck"):

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: FoodCategoryRepository::class)]
class FoodCategory
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'CUSTOM')]
    #[ORM\Column(type: UuidType::NAME, unique: true)]
    #[ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class: 'doctrine.uuid_generator')]
    #[Groups(['list_food_categories', 'show_food_category'])]
    private ?Uuid $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 30)]
    #[Groups(['list_food_categories', 'show_food_category'])]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['list_food_categories', 'show_food_category'])]
    private ?string $imageLink = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Truck::class, mappedBy: 'foodCategories')]
    #[Groups(['show_food_category'])]
    private Collection $trucks;
...
```

Here is my method to add a new truck in TruckController:

```
#[Route('/trucks', methods: ['POST'], name: 'add_truck')]
    public function add(#[MapRequestPayload] TruckCreationDto $truckDto, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, ValidatorInterface $validator, FoodCategoryRepository $foodCategoryRepository): JsonResponse
    {
        $context = new ObjectNormalizerContextBuilder();

        $responseData = new ResponseData();

        $errors = $validator->validate($truckDto);

        if (count($errors) > 0)
        {
            $responseData->setStatus(Status::ERROR);
            $responseData->addMessage((string) $errors);

            $statusCode = Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST;
        }
        else
        {
            $truck = new Truck();
            $truck->setName($truckDto->getName());
            $truck->setSiret($truckDto->getSiret());

            foreach($truckDto->getFoodCategories() as $foodCategory)
            {
                $foodCategory = $foodCategoryRepository->find($foodCategory);

                if($foodCategory)
                    $truck->addFoodCategory($foodCategory);
            }

            $entityManager->persist($truck);
            $entityManager->flush();

            $statusCode = Response::HTTP_CREATED;

            $responseData->setStatus(Status::SUCCESS);
            $responseData->addData('truck', $truck);

            $context->withGroups('show_truck');
        }

        return $this->json($responseData, $statusCode, $headers = [], $context->toArray());
    }
```

I am getting this error as a result of this method call:
`A circular reference has been detected when serializing the object of class "App\Entity\FoodCategory" (configured limit: 1).`

I can't get why.
My dev environment is under docker. Here is my .Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.2.12-apache-bullseye

WORKDIR /app

# Mise à jour des repositories
RUN apt update -y

# Installation de divers packages manquants
RUN apt install -y unzip wget

# Installation d'extensions PHP
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql

# Installation de composer
RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
RUN php composer-setup.php
RUN php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

# Installation Symfony CLI
RUN wget https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer -O - | bash
RUN mv /root/.symfony5/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony

# Installation du certificat auto-signé
RUN symfony server:ca:install

# Démarrage du serveur web
ENTRYPOINT ["symfony", "server:start"]
```

And the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  symfony-api:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - '/home/<user>/wsl_dev/symfony-api/:/app'
```

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the `MaxDepth` annotation on the `$foodCategories` property to control the depth of serialization? This can help prevent circular references in cases where `Truck` references `FoodCategory`, and `FoodCategory` references `Truck`, resulting in a loop during serialization.

```
#[MaxDepth(1)]
private Collection $foodCategories;
```

**Update**: The attribute `Ignore` will break the cycle

```
#[Ignore]
private Collection $foodCategories;
```

**Update 2**:

#[Groups(['list_food_categories', 'show_food_category', 'food_category_trucks'])]
class FoodCategory
{
// ...

```
#[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Truck::class, mappedBy: 'foodCategories')]
#[Groups(['show_food_category', 'food_category_trucks'])]
private Collection $trucks;

// ...
```

}

#[Groups(['list_trucks', 'show_truck', 'food_category_trucks'])]
class Truck
{
// ...

```
#[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: FoodCategory::class, inversedBy: 'trucks')]
#[Groups(['food_category_trucks'])]
private Collection $foodCategories;

// ...
```

}

Now, when you want to include the foodCategories property, you can use the `'food_category_trucks'` serialization group.

// In your controller or action

```
$serializedData = $serializer->serialize($foodCategory, 'json', ['groups' => 'food_category_trucks']);
```

Comment: Hi,
I will try it thank you but i even do not understand how it is possible that the FoodCategory is called since i do not use the group "show_truck"....

Comment: Same error after having tried with your proposal

Comment: I updated my answer add #[Ignore] over Collection `$foodCategories`

Comment: Thank you @Khribi Wessim, of course it works with the #[Ignore] attribute but what if i want to get all the trucks of FoodCategory? It will ignore the property too?

Comment: If you want to get all the trucks of a `FoodCategory` and you have marked the `foodCategories` property in the Truck entity with `#[Ignore]`, it will not be included in the serialization by default but you can check my update 2 to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are serializing a Truck entity which has a `$foodCategories` property:

```php
#[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: FoodCategory::class, inversedBy: 'trucks')]
private Collection $foodCategories;
```

and your `FoodCategory` also has a property that references `Truck`:

```php
#[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Truck::class, mappedBy: 'foodCategories')]
#[Groups(['show_food_category'])]
private Collection $trucks;
```

so when you go to return a `Truck` as JSON:

```
return $this->json($responseData, $statusCode, $headers = [], $context->toArray());
```

all of its properties, including `$foodCategories` are serialized. Since `$foodCategories` references the truck, the serializer ends up in a loop -- this is the circular reference the error is pointing at.

The solution to this usually involves adjusting the serialization depth as Khribi mentioned and/or to tell the serializer to ignore certain properties that cause the circular reference. In this case ignoring the `FoodCategory`'s `$trucks` property should solve this.

Ignoring properties can be done using the [`#[Ignore]` annotation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#option-1-using-ignore-attribute):

```php
// src/Entity/FoodCategory
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Ignore;

...
#[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Truck::class, mappedBy: 'foodCategories')]
#[Groups(['show_food_category'])]
#[Ignore]
private Collection $trucks;
```

Definitely check out Symfony's docs on the serializer component and specifically the section on [Handling circular references](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-circular-references).

Comment: Hi Adam and thank you for your help. 
Isn't it the aim of using the groups? Choosing the properties we want to return and avoid the circular reference error?

Comment: I believe that you're right that using the `#[Groups]` annotation is one way of managing which properties to serialize. I'm guessing the serializer service used by the controller when returning the JSON response isn't aware of the groups annotations. It's probably worth looking more closely at the [that section of the serializer component docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#attributes-groups).

Personally, I prefer using the `#[Ignore]` attribute for dealing with circular references since I find it more simple to reason about.